# Assign different type of balls into output containers with constraints

Tags: dataset, assignment, partitions

The problem is to asssign all differend kind inputs to outputs.
For example colored balls.

On the input we can receive max 5 different type of colored balls any with amount.

The amounts for the inputs are:
`I1, I2, I3, I4, I5`

We have 6 output with and each can be assigned for every type of color.
But after assigned an output for a type it can contain only that one and cannot be mixed with other type of color.

The outputs are paired so we have 3 pairs:
`A, B, C.`

The assigned amounts at the outputs are: `A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2`

For a pair of output we have a contraints such as the sum of the asssigned ball amount at an output in a group cannot be bigger then a given constant number:

```
MaxPairCapacity = 100
A1 + A2 <= MaxPairCapacity 
B1 + B2 <= MaxPairCapacity 
C1 + C2 <= MaxPairCapacity
```

The only rule for the inputs that their sum is always lower then the total assignable output capacity.

`I1 + I2 + I3 + I4 + I5 <= 3 * MaxPairCapacity`

We need to find one algorithm which assigns the inputs to outputs without remaining unassigned balls, or decide if there is a possible distribution for a given inputs.

A minimal working example:

```
MaxPairCapacity = 150

I1 = 200 red ball
I2 = 50 green ball
I3 = 50 purple ball
I4 = 50 black ball
I5 = 50 yellow ball

I1 + I2 + I3 + I4 + I5 <= 3 * MaxPairCapacity
200 + 50 + 50 + 50 + 50 <= 3 * 150
400 <= 450
So the total input is not bigger then the output.

Then we can try to assign:
100 red ball -> A1 
50 green -> A2 (A group is now reached max capacity)
50 pruple -> B1
50 black -> B2
50 yellow -> C1 
100 red -> C2

A group sum is 150
B group sum is 100
C group sum is 150  
So we found a possible distribution
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The symbol `Entity` has special meaning in Mathematica, so edit this out of your post. If by entity, you mean "type" as in Real/Integer/Complex, then indicate it as such. The symbol `Slot` also has a specialized meaning in Mathematica. If you present a **minimal working example** and a few pairs of inputs and desired outputs, then your problem will become clear to many more forum participants. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated the post  I hope it is more understandable now